# Remove blank lines from x axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a some trouble about removing the space in between x axis values. 
I want to remove the gap between two values in each `facet_wrap`

I checked this post 
[/ggplot-geom-tile-spacing-with-facets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625252/ggplot-geom-tile-spacing-with-facets) and this one [remove-blank-lines-from-plot-geom-tile-ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460918/remove-blank-lines-from-plot-geom-tile-ggplot?rq=1) but `scales=free_x` didnt helped at all.

Here is a reproducible example of mine

```
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)

x <-  rep(c(seq(2,40,length.out=8),seq(-2,-40,length.out=8)),times=1);
yy <- replicate(1,c(sort(10^runif(8,-9,1),decreasing=TRUE), sort(10^runif(8,-6,1),decreasing=TRUE),sort(10^runif(8,-3,0),decreasing=TRUE)))
direc <- rep(rep(c("A","B"),each=8),times=6)
add <-rep(seq(1:4),each=12)
df <- data.frame(x,yy,direc,add)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = yy, colour=direc)) +
  geom_point(size=5)+
  geom_line(size=1.3)+
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1e-7,1),breaks = c(3e-7,1e-3,1e-1,1))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=c(seq(-40,40,10)))+
  #scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0),drop=F)+
  #facet_grid(FIELD.Oe. ~ WER)+
  facet_wrap(~add)
```

[image]

I want to remove the gap between `A` and `B` factors. I need is to remove the unused values from x axis.

Comment: I don't see any reason to remove the gaps. Or you need a third factors.

Comment: @Pascal in my real dat that gap is much larger which makes a lot of space in each `facet_wrap`.

Comment: @Pascal I need something like in the first link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625252/ggplot-geom-tile-spacing-with-facets]

Comment: Then you have to introduce a break in x-axis. Are you looking for this?

Comment: @Pascal Yes. something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn `direc` into a factor with levels `c('B', 'A')` (to arrange facets with `B` on the left),

```
df$direc <- factor(direc, levels = c("B", "A"))
```

just replacing `facet_wrap` with a `facet_grid` does the trick.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = yy, colour = direc)) +
  geom_point(size=5)+
  geom_line(size=1.3)+
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1e-7,1),breaks = c(3e-7,1e-3,1e-1,1))+
  facet_grid(add ~ direc, scales = 'free')
```

Well, *a* trick; hopefully it's what you want:

[image: facet_grid version]

The `colour` argument is also technically unnecessary with this arrangement, though it doesn't cause any issues. I took out `scale_x_continuous`, as well, because it gets overridden by `scales = 'free'`.

Comment: Actually I tried that but it looks weird if you have many `add` values. the facet becomes narrower in the vertical axis.

Comment: You can just set the plot size to be taller and the facets will be more square. Well, depending on where the plot is going, I suppose; you might need to split it into multiple columns if you need the whole plot to be more square.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar thought to @alistaire but couldn't get `ggplot` to relinquish enough control, so I went with `cowplot::plot_grid()`.

I rearranged the factors by creating the order manually, with `B` appearing before `A`.

```
df$facet_order <- factor(paste0(df$direc,df$add), levels=c("B1", "A1", "B2", "A2", "B3", "A3", "B4", "A4"))
```

Creating the plots for `A` and `B` individually, then combining them using `plot_grid`;

```
g1 <- ggplot(data=df[df$direc=="B",], aes(x=x, y=yy)) +
  geom_point(size=5, col="red") +
  geom_line(size=1.3, col="red") +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1e-8,10), breaks = c(3e-7,1e-3,1e-1,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=c(seq(-40,40,10))) +
  facet_wrap(~facet_order, ncol=1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-50,0)) + theme(axis.line.x=element_line(colour="red", size=1.5),
                                         legend.position="none")
g2 <- ggplot(data=df[df$direc=="A",], aes(x=x, y=yy)) +
  geom_point(size=5, col="blue") +
  geom_line(size=1.3, col="blue") +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1e-8,10), breaks = c(3e-7,1e-3,1e-1,1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks=c(seq(-40,40,10))) +
  facet_wrap(~facet_order, ncol=1) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,50)) + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                                        axis.line.y=element_blank(),
                                        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
                                        axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
                                        axis.line.x=element_line(colour="blue", size=1.5),
                                        legend.position="none")
library(cowplot)
g <- plot_grid(g1,g2,scale=1.05)
g
```

[image: almost lined up]

Depending on the output size you're after, you can mess with the `size` argument to `plot_grid` and have the `x=0` label exactly overlap so that the data line up perfectly.

My suggestion (in the absence of simply not doing this) would be to do this for all the values of `add` so that you can manually move the relative x axes so that there is no gap for any of them.

Comment: I think the points chopped out by the `limits` argument to `scale_y_log10` got added back in here somehow. There are other ways to take them out, anyway, but if anyone else was really confused why B1 and A3 have 4 points here, that's why.

Comment: I changed the limits so that the points showed up and looked prettier. `coord_cartesian` is the better way to set the limits because it doesn't remove points outside the plot area.